# Today's launch of the Portuguese Stackoverflow website may have caused some issues with the SE sites list

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, portuguese-stackoverflow

The [Portuguese StackOverflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) website was launched a couple of hours ago, and out of curiosity the user @bigown went to see the main websites list, searching for the presence of this new one.

It is not present but there's a pertinent issue with the outputed data for "Unix & Linux":

[image: Screenshot]

[Link to the referred list.](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sites list will catch up after a bit.  Do not be alarmed, it's always caching.

Comment: [Caching caching caching caching](http://weebls-stuff.com/songs/badgers/)

Comment: And it should be fixed now!